# Intellij 14.1.4 CE spring boot 1.3.0.M1, spring-dev-tools hot reload not working

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot

Just started a spring boot application using spring initializer with spring-dev-tools and then imported into Intellij 14.1.4 CE. I can run the application fine with gradle `bootRun` but cannot get hot reload working. I follow the intro over here [Spring Dev Tools](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/17/devtools-in-spring-boot-1-3). Anything am missing?

Comment: IntelliJ 15 -> https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-141638. Also you should just run the main class not run it from within Gradle that won't work I guess.

Comment: I've tried running with the main class only but still no luck. Also I cannot find registry key referred in the link.

Comment: As stated you need IntelliJ 15 not 14.1.x...

Answer (score 0):

You should give a try to Spring Loaded : [Reference Guide - 72. Hot swapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html) (or [GitHub project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded))

Comment: That's older project that will be deprecated in favor of devtools. Basically, Pivotal thinks it's too brittle and too time consuming.