# Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 spring boot 1.3.0.M4, spring-dev-tools hot reload not working

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-boot, eclipse-luna

I've similar situation with Spring dev tools and Eclipse what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069648/intellij-14-1-4-ce-spring-boot-1-3-0-m1-spring-dev-tools-hot-reload-not-working) with IDEA. I've followed the configuration descibed in a [this](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/17/devtools-in-spring-boot-1-3) article, but hot reload is not working. Any ideas what I'm missing? This would be a really cool feature to have.

EDIT. Hot reload =  Any classpath file changes will automatically trigger an application restart.

My Gradle build script is:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.3.0.M4'
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
        classpath("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.2.RELEASE")
    }
}
```

And dependencies:

```
dependencies { 
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
runtime("com.h2database:h2")
runtime("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")}
```

Comment: and what does not work exactly?

Comment: Hot reloading, I edited original question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. For some reason Eclipse still tried to use previous Spring Boot version (1.2.5), after I deleted and reimported to project hot reloading started to work.